# Is there a way to get a nodes original XML string value from a node?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an XML document that is parsed into an XML document. I've tried setting XML.ignoreWhiteSpace and other properties to preserve the white space in the document but nothing is working. When I call node.toString() the white space has been removed.

Is there a method that returns the original raw text of the node?

For example, if I have the following XML, it is not returned the same when I use toString() or toXMLString():

Original:

```
<s:textFlow>

    <flow:TextFlow whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" version="3.0.0" xmlns:flow="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008"><flow:p><flow:span>A </flow:span><flow:span flow:fontWeight="bold">line</flow:span></flow:p></flow:TextFlow>
</s:textFlow>
```

Output:

```
<s:textFlow>
    <flow:TextFlow whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" version="3.0.0" xmlns:flow="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008"><flow:p><flow:span>A</flow:span><flow:span flow:fontWeight="bold">line</flow:span></flow:p></flow:TextFlow>
</s:textFlow>
```

Comment: Parsing an XML document  into an XML document ? Do you mean you parse a file into an object? What are you doing exactly? How does the code look like? Example XML?

Comment: When you pass in a string to an new XML(myValue) it creates nodes and then arranges them into a structured XML object. You see that structure in Flash Builder IDE debug view or when calling toXMLString(). But if you have certain flags set such as ignoreWhitespace then the XML is changed, sometimes drastically, sometimes subtlety. I'd like to know if the original raw text is kept around on the node itself and if there's a way get at it.

Comment: I'm hoping that maybe the XML class used in the run time may have been updated and have this feature and other parsing functions and hooks in the same way the RegExp engine may be updated https://discuss.as3lang.org/t/about-flash-runtime-2016/239.

Comment: OK, this clarifies a lot. I doubt that the original string is kept. The XML object is mutable, too. How would added nodes be incorporated into the string? Such redundancy of data is usually avoided. You might find what you are looking for in third party XML parsers.

Comment: If the node was modified the original data would be lost of course but in the same way they recognize the need for it by the existence of the toString and toXMLString() methods. I created a feature request for an new version of the XML parser here, https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4195700 if you get a chance vote on it.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the purpose of the `toXMLString()` method with some wishful thinking that it should do what you need. The intention of the method is to get **a** `String` representation of the object, **not** the original `String`. I don't think that a feature related to the original `String` should be in the standard library. As mentioned earlier, if you need more granular control over how the XML is parsed, you might want to look for a 3rd party library that does this. Good luck.

Comment: You mean writing an ANE? That might be a lot of work. What might be an acceptable alternative is a toUnformattedString()? That would be a completely unmodified output of the XML. That's what I need. But at import, when parsing a string and on export, the XML is at risk of being modified.

Comment: I'm talking about an alternative library to the built in `XML`, wether ANE or not doesn't matter. There's no way around that lot of work (the functionality you are asking for has to be created somehow, by someone) and I doubt that it's worth being implemented in the language for simple lack of demand. I doubt any library does the bookkeeping to remember which part of the string corresponds to which node in the tree. If you can find a library that allows you to hook into the parsing of the string, you have a chance to implement that yourself. Not without effort of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you tried

```
XML.ignoreWhitespace = false;
```

but did you also do

```
XML.prettyPrinting = false
```

Comment: I was looking for a method that's something along the lines of toRawString(). I think that by setting those flags to false (and also ignoreProcessingInstructions) I might be able to achieve the same effects but I would have to be setting those flags before import and when calling the toString methods.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts why don't you check if out and get back with the results?

Comment: It seems that setting all of those values returns the closest thing to the original as possible.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks! OK it matters that the XML string is not modified when creating an XML object. So those three flags need to be set to false on import (creating an XML from a string) and those three flags need to also be set to false when calling toString().

Comment: @1.21gigawatts good to hear that! might be helpful to others facing the same issue if you have time you could update your question and add your new findings! Ciao!